# ~/.bashrc colourings not coming through to Terminal correctly

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

There must be some error in my bash code that is preventing my terminal from correctly displaying colours.

My `~/.bashrc` file is as follows:

```
# Allow colours for terminal
export TERM="rxvt"

BLACK=$(tput setaf 0)
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
LIME_YELLOW=$(tput setaf 190)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
POWDER_BLUE=$(tput setaf 153)
BLUE=$(tput setaf 4)
MAGENTA=$(tput setaf 5)
CYAN=$(tput setaf 6)
WHITE=$(tput setaf 7)

BRIGHT=$(tput bold)
NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)
BLINK=$(tput blink)
REVERSE=$(tput smso)
UNDERLINE=$(tput smul)

PS1='\[${RED}\]\u\[${BLUE}\]@\[${CYAN}\]\h\[${GREEN}\] :: \[${BLUE}\]\W\[${GREEN}\] \$\[${WHITE}\] '

alias ls="ls -G"
```

my `~/.bash_profile` is:

```
[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc
```

When I paste the contents of my `~/.bashrc` file into the terminal, I get the output I am after as follows:

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be setting `TERM`. That's almost never the right thing to do. (Probably not related to your problem but it isn't correct nonetheless.)

Comment: Notice how your prompt changes when you run those entries also? Your `.bashrc` file isn't being used at all. Are you sure your `.bash_profile` is being used at all? (Also do you want the white coloring running off the end of the prompt like that?) I assume running `source ~/.bashrc` in your terminal also works?

Comment: @EtanReisner I have a similar problem... Why is setting `TERM` a bad idea?

Comment: Are you using `rxvt`? All the time? What about when you aren't? Why don't you let your terminal set the value to represent what it actually is? Why do you think you know better? What problem are you solving there?

Comment: I tried source ~/.bashrc but it does not work..